# Capturing an image and uploading it to a database

Tags: java, android

I want to upload image from camera into database. I already solved the problem from gallery image from gallery already uploaded to database but it wont work on from camera or capture image, i tried to code the same with gallery but i having a error.

Here is my code.

Here is my **Android Manifest.xml** code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**MainActivity**

This is my submit button

```
reportsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageUploadToServerFunction();
     }
  });
}
```

**This is my code to upload image into database**

```
public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bytes);
    byte[] byteArrayVar = bytes.toByteArray();
    final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, Base64.DEFAULT);

}
```

**This is my code to open open the Camera**

```
private void openCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

**This is my OnActivityResult code**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (attachment >= 1 && attachment <= 8) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                if (attachment == 1) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
                } else if (attachment == 2) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview1);
                } else if (attachment == 3) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview2);
                } else if (attachment == 4) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview3);
                } else if (attachment == 5) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview4);
                } else if (attachment == 6) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview5);
                } else if (attachment == 7) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview6);
                } else if (attachment == 8) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview7);
                }

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                dynamic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (attachment == 1) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
                } else if (attachment == 2) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview1);
                } else if (attachment == 3) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview2);
                } else if (attachment == 4) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview3);
                } else if (attachment == 5) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview4);
                } else if (attachment == 6) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview5);
                } else if (attachment == 7) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview6);
                } else if (attachment == 8) {
                    dynamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview7);
                }

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            dynamic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imageBitmap);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            Toast.makeText(report.this,"Here "+ getRealPathFromURI(tempUri),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
        System.out.print(resultCode);
    }
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Don't inflate images in your database. Store the image paths only.

Comment: the problem seems to be `Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");` . the `data` contains the `URI` to the image. not the bitmap iteself.

Comment: I've got this error ImageUploadToServerFunction();